# Foreach loop in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, model, product

I'm using the CI framework and I'm trying to make a foreach loop so that all products of my site are displayed.

This is my controller file:

```
class AlleCadeausController extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('allecadeaus_model');
    $data['cadeaus'] = $this->allecadeaus_model->get_cadeaus();
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus');   
}
```

This is my model file:

```
<?php 
class Allecadeaus_model extends CI_Model {
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }
    public function get_cadeaus()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products');     
        $result = $query->result_array();    
        return $result;
    }
}
```

this is my view:

```
<?php
foreach ($cadeaus as $cadeau)
{
    echo $cadeau->product_naam;
}
?>
```

The error is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: cadeaus
>
> Filename: views/allecadeaus.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/allecadeaus.php Line: 3
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/AlleCadeausController.php
>   Line: 11 Function: view
>
> File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

My table name is `products`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You havn't passed the `$data` variable in your controller. Please follow below code:

```
$this->load->view('allecadeaus', $data);
```

So, your controller function should be like below.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('allecadeaus_model');
    $data['cadeaus'] = $this->allecadeaus_model->get_cadeaus();
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus', $data);


}
```

Cheers, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('allecadeaus_model');
    $data['cadeaus'] = $this->allecadeaus_model->get_cadeaus();
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus',$data);


}
```

try this in you controller

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pass data to the view you just load view. 
for passing data to view you have to do

```
$this->load->view('allecadeaus',$data);
```

[Here are good documentation for passing data from controller to view](https://selftaughtcoders.com/displaying-data-codeigniter-view/) [Contact ME](http://www.jagdish.96.lt)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the data to the view follow the below code:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('allecadeaus_model');
    $data['cadeaus'] = $this->allecadeaus_model->get_cadeaus();
    $this->load->view('allecadeaus, $data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $data with the view.

```
$this->load->view('allecadeaus',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass array of data in second argument.
Please use this :

```
$this->load->view('allecadeaus',$data);
```

If you load child view in allecadeaus, then you don't need to pass array of data. You can directly access all variables from array of data.